# I have index.php and other files, how do I display other pages?

Tags: pages, templates

I'm converting an HTML theme into WP. I have index.php, header.php, footer.php, which are from HTML.

Then I created pages from within admin area like about-us etc. Created a menu and linked those pages to the menu. The menu is showing fine, but instead of pages I created WP is displaying index.php. So I guess I need a template to display about-us and other pages.

If it's a duplicate please post a link in a comment, I mean an exact duplicate not something  that I have to sit and guess the answer. Thanks

I tried to read [an article in Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates) but its not well written, sounds like gibberish. Should be straighforward, I just need to display pages I created from within the admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template for the page is called `page.php` and should be in the same theme folder as index.php (alternatively you can use the `is_page()` function to do a template inside index.php but it's more difficult and there's little point to that). 
Best way forward is to study an existing theme and figure how things work. A look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) should help as well.

Comment: Thank you Lucian, that's what I figuered. I copied page.php from another template, but it doesn't work, I thought I could see at least partial page. Yes, let me examine the code.

Comment: Ah ok, got it working, turns out I uploaded to another project folder duh...